# Is it required to have deep knowledge of lower levels to write efficient Java code?

Tags: java, assembly, hardware, bytecode

All is in the title:

Is it required to have deep knowledge of lower levels to write efficient Java code ?

Comment: You can ask to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for your clear point of view.

Comment: FYI : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/34890/how-to-learn-java

Comment: What is programmers.SE ?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com although i think this question has more to do with code than with organization, and is as a consequence prefectly well suited here.

Comment: more to do with code, but this is subjective !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at all!

Java abstracts away pretty much all of the underlying levels, unlike C where you have direct access to hardware and memory or Assembly, where you're actually coding in terms of the actual registers and buffers.

To write efficient Java code, you just need to ensure the efficiency of whatever algorithms you're using: if you have an inefficient algorithm it will stay inefficient no matter what you program it in. Additionally, you have to make sure you're using the correct type of data structures. That's one reason why people code in assembly: it allows you to create some very flexible data structures. But for mainstream purposes, the classes found in java.util will be more than sufficient.

In modern machines, any cost caused by using a virtual machine is negligible, so again java doesn't have much of a disadvantage compared to assembly or c.

You can't mix Java and Assembly code anyway, so knowledge of the language wouldn't help, but what would help is knowledge of efficient algorithms (sorting, etc.) and data structures (linkedlists, trees, etc.)

Comment: this is misleading: as with any language, knowledge about the language runtime/implementation is necessary to design efficient algorithms and datastructures; for Java, this includes some rudimentary knowledge about the GC and its limitations (weak references come to mind...)

Comment: @Christoph It seems like programming with the intention of lower level optimisation often ends up slowing down code because the interactions are more complicated than can be worked through (and making it generally poorer quality code). Clean code and measurement are the most important tools.

Comment: @Tom: I'm not (exclusively) talking about micro-optimization, but about intrinsic properties of the execution environment: most C implementations favor iteration over recursion (a high-level decision), in (current) Javascript, `for..in` is slower than `for(;;)` when iterating over arrays (admittedly, a micro-optimization and a bad example because of the semantic differences between the statements), in Java, you need to understand when and why to use `StringBuilder`, `WeakReference`, `ArrayList` vs `LinkedList`, `volatile`, all of which relates to properties of the implementation...